# Adding ram to a consumer printer?

Tags: memory, printer

A friend of mine needs to print an 180 page PDF using a basic HP laser printer. Halfway through the printing process the printer starts printing blanks. What could be issue? The friend is thinking that the printer runs out of ram for larger PDFs. Could something else be the issue. We tried updating to the latest printer driver, but that didn't help.

Edit:

The printer is an HP m401dn LaserJet. I connected the printer to my own laptop and the problem went away. The friend's computer is pretty ancient. Could adding more ram to his machine help fix the problem?

Comment: are you sure it's not out of ink? If it runs out of memory, it should print what it can buffer, then ask the driver for more. Does it help if the app responsible for the print is not closed during the print?

Comment: I have seen printers with low amounts of RAM die on complex PS jobs.  So it could be an issue

Comment: It is not unusual that a single page of a high-quality image print does not fit the printer memory. This is why the printers sometimes pause for a while while printing HQ photos.

Comment: Can you print pages 1-40 then separately print pages 41-80?

Comment: exactly which HP laser printer is this?

Comment: More memory is *almost* always good, but I don’t think low memory is the problem here; you said it worked when you tried it with your system, so it’s not the printer. Also, how did you determine that it was blanking half-way through? Did it happen only once? If so, then low ink does seem like an explanation (did you add ink when you switched to your system?) Did you try printing the whole job more than once and it always blanked half-way through? If so, **bad you!** The second time, you should have set it to print where it left off and print only the pages you needed, not *all* of them again.

Comment: You will be unable to upgrade the memory on the printer.  It uses non-standard parts which are a soldered solution.  How large is this PDF exactly?

Comment: @ramhound 180 pages-5.6 megs.

Comment: @synetech it blanks every time on his laptop in various pages. This is an actual book that requires binding.

Comment: @Absolute0 - I have printed files 5x larger then that on similar hardware.  In other words that file is actually pretty small.

Answer (score 1):

That printer has [256MB of memory](http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/products/printers/product-detail.html?oid=5096262#!tab=specs) which is already quite a bit for a printer. Few printers go beyond that because it is generally enough for pretty much any print-job that a consumer (or even a lot of companies and businesses) would have.

There is something else wrong and that it works without problem on your system is proof of that. The problem is clearly with your friend’s computer, especially since [nobody else](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/topIssuesResults/?sp4ts.oid=5096252) [has reported](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/mostViewedResults/?sp4ts.oid=5096252) [the issue](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/search/?sp4ts.oid=5096252&spf_p.tpst=kbSearchMain&spf_p.pbp_kbSearchMain_searchState_noResFound=true&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#searchResultHead). You can try posting at the [HP forum](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-LaserJet/bd-p/bsc-413) for much more targeted help and feedback from HP technicians.

Before resorting to re-installing Windows, try re-installing the drivers. If you have already tried the [latest drivers](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?cc=us&lang=en&sp4ts.oid=5096260&ac.admitted=1384802147853.876444892.492883150) for it, then what may have happened is that there were remnants left behind. Try doing a [full](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Printing-Questions/Need-help-to-COMPLETELY-uninstall-HP-drivers-amp-software-fm/td-p/498183) [un-installation](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c02259020#N1019) [of all HP software](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-All-in-One-Software-Drivers/Unable-to-install-HP8500-drivers/m-p/251037#M11640) and using an [HP removal utility](http://google.com/search?q=hp%20removal%20utility).

Unfortunately, it’s going to be a bit of time-consuming, annoying work to shuffle the drivers and reboot and stuff to get the other computer cleaned up and working with the printer, but on the bright side, there’s no hardware defects, so it’s only a matter of fixing a software issue, and software problems are always better than hardware problems because they can usually be fixed for free.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting it to print directly to the printer. Open Devices and Printers, then right click the printer and choose Printer Properties (not properties). Click Advanced, and you'll see options for spooling. One will be to print directly to the printer. You can try this option

Comment: You can also try ticking the "Start printing after last page is spooled" button under the same Advanced tab. That often fixes problems with large print jobs. Unlike printing direct, this does not tie up the PC for the duration of the print job. I do not think RAM is the problem.